# Default property values for WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, default-value

I have the following scenario:

There is a complex object that is residing in the standalone class library and some of the object properties have default values.

The object is argument for WCF public method.

I instantiate this object on the client of WCF, assign values to properties and pass it to the WCF public method.

The WCF method on service side accepts it and does whatever.

My problem is that when I instantiate the object on the client property default values are not available for me to use and I have to assign them in code again.

I looked through the past questions on the topic here and did not find anything related to my scenario. I don't really have data contract for the argument although on the client my object gets instantiated not from the class library itself but from the service reference, like WCFServiceReference.MyClass (otherwise WCF method can not accept it as argument).

I would really like to have all those default values to be available on the client.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With your approach -- using the service proxy classes -- the client only gets the properties marked with `DataMember`.  That's why the default values you assign don't appear in the client -- that code is not serialized, so it's not sent with the WCF service.

If you want to share code, you can do it by declaring your `DataContract` classes in a separate class library.  Have the WCF service and the client both reference that library.

Comment: Hi dbaseman, thank you for the answer. I already had my classes in a separate library. Decorating class members with DataMember did not help me but I think I now understand why. While reading your post I have got an idea of how get around of the issue - I have just created a public method of WCF service that returns the object I need with default values preset in that method. I upvoted your answer since it prompted me for that insight.

Comment: @Anvar no prob, hope it helps!